# Rails and Heroku - how to display XML file on URL "example.com/file"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, sitemap

A client has a website running on Heroku and files are stored on Amazon S3.
The sitemap map is set up on URL: `website.com/sitemap.xml` -> after entering this URL address into browser is made redirect to `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/sitemap.xml`. The XML has like 30MB.

But now the client wants to display the XML file straight on `website.com/sitemap.xml`, no redirect to Amazon S3.
If I asked his why, he wrote me "because it requires Google Webmasters".

I would like to ask you, if there is any way to display the content of `sitemap.xml` straight on `website.com/sitemap.xml`... or, if there is any way to solve this.

Thank you, have a nice day!

Comment: There is a trick I found just lately,
you can read about it here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570936/2529330

Answer (score 0):

So for now i don't see any option but download sitemap.xml from  s3 and then render it in your application.

use net/http do download the page.