# What should I be using for sitemap generation for rails on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, sitemap

As a beginner to rails, I'm finding the generation of sitemaps on Heroku to be extremely daunting due to its read-only limitations. However, a sitemap is fundamental to my website as its success is based on SEO.

I have tried dynamic_sitemaps gem however soon removed it as I realised it had no documentation for heroku use. I then used the sitemap_generator gem which had coverage of heroku integration using several gems and external platforms such as Amazon S3. The problem however is that as a beginner I'm running into issues and finding it hard to get past them.

Is there a solution I can use easily generate sitemaps for consistent content such as blog posts on the heroku platform? I really want to get up and running and feel this could take a while to configure if I have to use the methods I've already attempted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a small trick that makes it possible to dynamically generate the sitemap file but persist it for later calls **on Heroku**.

It works great for small\medium size projects, if you have a big\huge project and thousand of pages that changes endlessly , please consider using S3 to store the sitemap file.

Those are the steps:

1. use the `sitemap_generator` gem as instructed here https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator
2. after `bundle`, run `rake sitemap:install`, it will create a *config/sitemap.rb* file for you
3. edit the *config/sitemap.rb* file to look like this

   `SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = [your host name goes here]`

   `SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp').to_s`

   `SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.compress = false`

   `SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do`

   `[all your site pages add commands goes here]`

   `end`

- regarding the host name, I suggest it to be `"#{ENV['HOST_PROTOCOL']}://#{ENV['HOST_NAME']}"` (and of course add the appropriate environment variables) so you could change it on different environments.
- regarding compress, start with false, make sure all is working great for you and change it later if it is a big file.

4. create your sitemap controller file - *app/controllers/sitemap_controller.rb*
5. Edit the sitemap controller file to look like this

`require 'rake'`

```
class SitemapController < ApplicationController
  def index
    file_name = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemap.xml').to_s
    
    unless File.exist?(file_name)
      Rails.application.load_tasks
      Rake::Task['sitemap:refresh:no_ping'].invoke
    end
    
    # it's better to be safe than sorry 
    if File.exist?(file_name)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { render file: file_name }
      end
    else
      render file: 'public/404.html', status: :not_found, layout: false
    end
  end
end
```

6. Add the index action to your routes.rb file

`resources :sitemap, only: %i[index], constraints: ->(req) { req.format == :xml }`

7. restart/deploy you server and go to /sitemap.xml

Enjoy

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Thanks! One little thing. You may need to render your file without layout like this `format.xml { render file: file_name, layout: false }`

Comment: I ended up going the extra steps to use S3, but appreciate this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have taken a look to [Dynamic Site Maps Gem](https://github.com/lassebunk/dynamic_sitemaps)  this is really simple to set up just read the read me in the Github for more features you can also look at [Site Map Generator gem](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator)

Wish you the best of luck

Answer (score 0):

try like this

Controller

```
class SitemapController < ApplicationController


layout nil

def index
  @static_pages = [jobs_url, advertising_url, join_url]
  @offers = Offer.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml
  end
end

end
```

View

```
    xml.instruct!
xml.urlset(

) do
  @static_pages.each do |page|
    xml.url do
      xml.loc "#{page}"
      xml.changefreq("monthly")
    end
  end
  @offers.each do |offer|
    xml.url do
      xml.loc 
      xml.changefreq("daily")
    end
  end


end
```

Route

```
 get 'sitemap.xml', :to => 'sitemap#index', :defaults => { :format => 'xml' }
```