# Invoke rake task from Heroku Scheduler

Tags: heroku, scheduler, sitemap

How can I invoke a rake task from the Heroku scheduler?

I need to invoke the command `rake sitemap:refresh` (from an external library)

```
# scheduler.rake

task :sitemap_refresh => :environment do
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  Rake::Task['-s sitemap:refresh'].invoke
end
```

Comment: Why are you using Heroku scheduler for this?

Comment: @SNeumann is there a better way to regularly schedule a rake task?

Comment: depends on your use case. you may want to use background workers invoked from your code which is more reliable, or use a cron based scheduler such as Cron To Go which works essentially like Heroku Scheduler but with more control on schedule, better reliability and the option to manually run tasks as well (I'm affiliated with Cron To Go).

Comment: you can use the code in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570936/2529330

Answer (score 0):

Use this as the command: `bundle exec rake sitemap:refresh`